# Parse through array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, mixed

I am getting the following array of objects as response when printing a variable called `$userStatistic`.

```
OnApp_User_BillingStatistics Object
        (
            [_tagRoot] => vm_stat
            [_resource] => vm_stats
            [fields:protected] => 
            [dynamicFields:protected] => Array
                (
                    [] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [created_at] => 2012-11-01T00:00:22Z
                            [currency_code] => AUD
                            [id] => 1459
```

How can I parse through this and get the value of `created_at` and the other things.? I have tried to use `$userStatistic->created_a`t. But it is not returning anything. Then I tried with `$userStatistic[0]->created_at`. But it is throwing Fatal error as

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type OnApp_User_BillingStatistics as array

How can I parse through this mixed variable ??

NB : For the other responses which don't have this square brackets after Array in `dynamicFieldsm`, I am able to access data using `$userStatistic->created_at`

Answer (score 1):

It's not an array of objects, it's an object containing an array.
Using -> for the object variables and [] for the array, created at is
 `$userStatistic->dynamicFields[0]->created_at`

Comment: it's protected, you will get a "Cannot access protected property" exception, no?

Comment: The dynamicFields is there in the API response as debugging is turned on. So I am not getting any value for this call.

Comment: For all the other API calls its response is like `OnApp_User Object
(
    [_tagRoot] => user
    [_resource] => user
    [version:protected] => 3
    [_release] => 
  
    [dynamicFields:protected] => Array
        (
            [_activated_at] => 2012-11-02T15:36:54+11:00
            [] => 
            [_billing_plan_id] => ` and I am accessing this as $user->_activated_at and it is displaying the correct value, But here the [] comes after Array and it makes issues